# SFR Breeders on Small Mars Moon feasibility

Tags: fluid-dynamics, space-expansion, nuclear-engineering

Need help with a topic for a sci-fi book. Basic premise is 200yr in future, mining facility on small Mars moon of Phobos. Power source we would like is an SFR breeder as we think this would be cost effective for fuel. What I need to know. Phobos has $0.0057$ m/s$^2$ of gravity and I need know how the heck would liquid sodium operate in that environment. I know without oxygen liquid sodium at high temp wouldn't react if released however is there a point the temp in an SFR reactor can get so hot it explodes vice a standard melt down?

BTW I am Gas Turbine tech and understand a good bit of tech but Space and Nuclear is a little too far in left field for me.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [worldbuilding.se]

Comment: Agreed, it belongs on Worldbuilding. I'll answer it anyway.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The place to put this is the Worldbuilding Forum. They consider this kind of question *all the time* there.

The two new things you must deal with are lack of gravity, and vacuum.

Without gravity, you can't depend on hot liquid to rise and cold liquid to fall. But you didn't depend on that anyway, you always use pumps. So that's OK.

If you hvae a vessel with liquid and gas both, you can't depend on the liquid to stay at the bottom and the gas at the top. So you probably want a design that doesn't have mixed liquid and gas. Do you anywhere depend on a compressible gas to buffer volumes, when the liquid volume changes? That could be an issue. Maybe replace that with a piston that can change volume.

That's probably all that matters from low gravity. Except for all the little things we haven't thought of.

Vacuum means that you are basicly running your heat exchange inside a thermos bottle. It isn't easy to get rid of heat, and your reactor is a heat engine. You could have a bunch of fins to radiate heat away? Those would be less effective in sunlight, but the farther you are from the sun the less that matters. It might work better to conduct your heat into the nearby rock. The hotter rocks would conduct it to farther rocks, and hotter rocks at the surface would radiate it away. You'd have to make sure that the rocks around your base don't get uncomfortably hot.

Think about accidents. There will be an accident. The vacuum won't provide oxygen to burn the sodium, but if you use water as a secondary heat exchange, the water will make a mess. The sodium will make a mess regardless. Let's assume that the radioactive stuff won't cause a problem -- any problem it causes would be the same for other nuclear designs too. You can expect to get sodium on all sorts of things near the wrecked power plant. It will boil away in vacuum and spatter things. You wind up with solid sodium and (if there's water) sodium hydroxide etc littering the landscape. Anybody who goes outside anywhere near can expect to get sodium and sodium hydroxide particles on the outside of his protective gear, which will have amusing results when he goes indoors. You should probably arrange to thoroughly wash off anybody who comes in from outdoors, before they remove protective gear. Build that into the base design, on the assumption there will be an accident. It's a lot better than having to add it to the design later, after an emergency.

In your story, you probably should have a nuclear accident in the background, at least one has already happened and people are dealing with the long-term results.